# PostGIS latitude longitude radius

Tags: geolocation, postgis, latitude-longitude

I have two tables A and B:

- A contains lat and long values for entity.
- B contains lat, long, point and radius values.

I need to make a SQL query that selects all rows from A table inside the radius from B table.

Can somebody show me a SQL query example?

Comment: Provide sample data and expected results if you want more curated answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    a.*
    , b.id
FROM
    a
JOIN
    b
ON
    ST_DWithin(b.point, ST_MakePoint(a.long, a.lat), b.radius)
```

Take into account that:

- This query does not remove duplicated rows on a. Those that are whihin the distance of more that one row on b
- The coordinates of bot tables are expected to be in the same srid
- b.radius is expected to be in the [same distance unit that the srid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) you are using

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to test it. Sorry for delay.